# Nested cgroups: How a parent distributes resources when it has processes in it AND child cgroups with processes in them?

Tags: cgroups

I've been studying containerization in-depth in the context of docker and kubernetes, and one thing didn't quite click in my mind just yet, and I couldn't find an answer to it, which is exactly what the title says.

Suppose:

- I have a parent cgroup "**A**" with access to 50% CPU, and 2 process running in it (PID 1 and 2), both using non-stop 25% absolute CPU each.
- Then I add a child cgroup "**A1**" to it, asking everything **A** can give (shares=1024 & quota/period ratio = 1.0), with 2 other process attached to it (PIDs 3 and 4).

How would CPU be distributed between these 4 process in different hierarchy levels?

The way I think of it, is PID 1, 2 and cgroup A1 would share equal 1/3s of A's 50%, so:

- PID 1: 16.66666%
- PID 2: 16.66666%
- cgroup A1: 16.66666% (Which means, PID 3 and 4 would get 8.3333% CPU each).

Is it right? Doest it makes sense, or am I missing on something?

If it is not right, how should I educate myself to "visualize" this multi-hierarchy level distribution better and think of it in a more intuitive way?